# Prototype property not defined inside a constructor of a custom OL3 control

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, google-closure

I'm trying to create custom control in ol3. I've met [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/measure.html) and decided to make some class instead of one big pile of code all over the page. So I've got something like that:

```
var MeasureLength = function ( opt_options ) {
    var options = opt_options || {};

    var button = document.createElement( 'button' );
    button.innerText = 'M';

    button.addEventListener( 'click', this._trigger, false );

    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    element.className = 'measure-length ol-control';
    element.appendChild( button );

    ol.control.Control.call( this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
    } );
};

MeasureLength.prototype._trigger = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Activating!");
};

ol.inherits( MeasureLength, ol.control.Control );
```

The problem is that `_trigger` is not called. One way to make it work is to place `_trigger` inside the constructor:

```
var _trigger = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Activating!");
};
button.addEventListener( 'click', _trigger, false );
```

But I don't like that way because the code in one pile again and all OOP is crashing down.

So my question is: What is the best practice to create custom controls in ol3 when you have a lot of code?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of `inherits` and the definition of `trigger`? IIRC, closure replaces the child prototype when using `inherits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure's `inherits` function overwrites the child's `prototype` by an instance of the parent.

If you attach the `_triggered` attribute after calling `inherits`, it should be available in your child constructor:

```
var MeasureLength = function ( opt_options ) {
    // should now be available
    console.log(this._trigger);
};

ol.inherits( MeasureLength, ol.control.Control );

MeasureLength.prototype._trigger = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Activating!");
};
```